# post data with different action name but url doesn't change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an Index page with a Search function to show the data. After type in the criteria (or without criteria), I'm submitting the request using POST method to different action name (Search action) but the result is returned to the Index view.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
{
    // criteria fields
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // preparing the view model
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(HomeViewModel vm)
{
    // get the data
    return View("Index", vm);
}
```

This change the url into http://localhost:12345/Home/Search which I don't want to be displayed. I can change the Search action name to Index, so get and post request will use the same name, but is there any way to make the url unchanged?

I've tried to add a new route into RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Search",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" }
);
```

but it doesn't work, I've got 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are following default implementation. Means when you post data , it will submit form to post method and which is correct. You can solve by this two way.

1. Use ajax to post to Url so it will not change Url In Browser.
2. Use Redirect to Index.

   ```
     public ActionResult Index()
       {
           if(Session["IndexVM"] != null)
                 return View((HomeViewModel )Session["IndexVM"]);
           return View();
       }
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Search(HomeViewModel vm)
       {
           // your search code
           Session["IndexVM"] = vm;
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First, if I change to ajax, then it took much time because I have to change the paging and sorting also, so I'm using the second option and use TempData. Btw, can this be done by adding a route in RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: Route is for incoming request not for outgoing request. In your case when you display first time then it is Index and when you post it will post to Search method and you are returning view so it can be any view but it does not affect the url. In this case route is not help. Now tempdata or Session it is up to you.  TempData is one layer above the Session.